# enable only logged in user to view working hours field

Tags: python-3.x, xml, odoo-11

i want to hide working hours field (view only for employee itself) by attrs based on computed field

```
<record id="hide_working_hours_for_employees" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">Hide Working Hours Employees Form</field>
  <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='resource_calendar_id']" position="before">
      <field name="working_hours_view"/>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='resource_calendar_id']" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('working_hours_view' ,'=', False)]}</attribute>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

i made computed field but it doesn't work

```
    def _hide_working_hours(self):
    current_user = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Current User', default=lambda self: self.env.user.id)
    if current_user != uid:
        return False
    else:
        return True


   working_hours_view = fields.Boolean(computed=_hide_working_hours)
```

Comment: you cannot create new field inside a method.

Comment: no it's out of function (but in same class) .. i write it wrongly just here but it's right in my code

Comment: so please fix your code @omar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view or hide field by attrs based on function (Automatically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267563/how-to-view-or-hide-field-by-attrs-based-on-function-automatically)