# How to view or hide field by attrs based on function (Automatically)?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-11

I want to view 'working_hours' field only for employee, his manager and 'hr.group_hr_user' group.
how to hide this field **automatically without edit form or trigger a button**

```
class InheritHrEmployee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'


    def hide_working_hours(self):
        if self.env.uid == self.user_id.id or self.env.uid == self.parent_id.user_id.id or self.env.user.has_group(
            'hr.group_hr_user'):
            self.working_hours_view = True
        else:
            self.working_hours_view = False

    working_hours_view = fields.Boolean(computed=hide_working_hours)
```

**XML:**

```
<record id="hide_working_hours_for_employees" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">Hide Working Hours Employees Form</field>
  <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='resource_calendar_id']" position="before">
      <field name="working_hours_view" invisible="1"/>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='resource_calendar_id']" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('working_hours_view' ,'=', False)]}</attribute>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for display working hours field only `hr.group_hr_user` group users.

**XML:**

```
<record id="hide_working_hours_for_employees" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">Hide Working Hours Employees Form</field>
  <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='resource_calendar_id']" position="before">
      <field name="working_hours_view" invisible="1"/>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='resource_calendar_id']" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="groups">hr.group_hr_user</attribute>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

You can add multiple attributes in the XML file like above code.

Comment: i used attrs based on computed field .. and it works now

Comment: Okay That's fine.

Answer (score 0):

i added the field before the function and it works now automatically

```
class InheritHrEmployee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'

    inv = fields.Boolean(string="Invisible", compute="c_inv", store=False)

    @api.one
    def c_inv(self):
        if self.env.uid == self.user_id.id or self.env.uid == self.parent_id.user_id.id or self.env.user.has_group(
             'hr.group_hr_user'):
            self.inv = False
        else:
            self.inv = True
```

.. like this example
[make fields visible to user and invisible to other](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-make-fields-visible-to-stock-user-and-invisible-to-stock-manager-except-admin-in-odoo10-139892?fbclid=IwAR06SZEXQORaLbo4zp56ch0X3HXJcj8Js8R185HnVrjLfrdUzfwBRBV8VNU)